# Wide to Long preserving a group

Tags: r

How would I transform the following `data.frame` from wide to long while also generating a group column?

Example data:

```
dat <- data.frame(ID=paste0("id",1:10),readout1_g1=rnorm(10),readout1_g2=rnorm(10),readout1_g3=rnorm(10),readout2_g1=rnorm(10),readout2_g2=rnorm(10),readout2_g3=rnorm(10))
```

I have the following groups I am interested in that are part of the column names

```
groups <- c("g1","g2","g3","g1","g2","g3")

dat
     ID readout1_g1 readout1_g2 readout1_g3 readout2_g1 readout2_g2 readout2_g3
1   id1   0.2732715  -0.6328317  -1.3024276   1.7248944  -0.3343275  1.36908631
2   id2   2.0209029  -0.8575063   0.6022883  -0.9226497   1.4893213 -0.98697968
3   id3   1.6034079   0.8023266   1.0845380   1.2936800  -0.7395568 -0.29720316
4   id4  -1.5122641  -2.5982733   0.4245139  -1.2592326   1.5311672  0.38242248
5   id5   0.8096931  -0.6260401   0.7163551   0.2675392   0.8919616  0.01563483
6   id6  -0.8557278   0.1875746   1.3020202   0.4973898   2.7477934  0.38654868
7   id7   0.1556841  -1.1668916   0.6434463  -0.2245761  -0.6832238 -2.50482389
8   id8   0.7511197   0.4819956   0.2385116  -1.0582192   0.1067799  2.15636372
9   id9  -0.4613545  -1.2080645   1.3165922  -2.1785463  -1.2692302 -0.44555107
10 id10   0.3601222  -0.2414607  -1.5775119   2.0834873  -0.4656254  1.58457613
```

I would like to obtain the following long format:

```
ID readout1 readout2 group
id1 value value g1
id2 value value g1
...
id10 value value g3
```

I tried using `pivot_longer` in its most simple form but the rows were not ordered by groups properly in that rows having `g1` for `readout1` and `g2` for `readout2` for example.

Comment: You're correct, google did not lead me to this unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `pivot_longer` to extract the group followed by `pivot_wider` to restore the `readout` columns:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID, names_pattern = "(.*)_(.*)", names_to = c("name", "grp")) %>% 
  pivot_wider()
```

This returns

```r
# A tibble: 30 x 4
   ID    grp   readout1 readout2
   <chr> <chr>    <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 id1   g1      0.732    0.499 
 2 id1   g2     -0.301   -0.0941
 3 id1   g3      0.198    1.62  
 4 id2   g1      0.653    0.732 
 5 id2   g2     -0.325    1.49  
 6 id2   g3     -0.0475  -1.73  
 7 id3   g1     -1.59     1.25  
 8 id3   g2     -1.59     0.688 
 9 id3   g3     -0.738    0.341 
10 id4   g1      1.12     1.11  
# ... with 20 more rows
```